# Does facebook have the data about when a user adds a reaction to a post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to collect data about a post on facebook from its graph api. I am able to get all the other information (like comments, when the comment was created, who created it, etc etc) but i am not able to find the timestamp on the reactions. That is i want find out at what time (and date) did the user add the reaction. **Does facebook have this information? If yes, then how do i get that information using graph api?**

Answer (score 1):

> Does facebook have this information?

Most likely they do.

> If yes, then how do i get that information using graph api?

You don’t, because they do not provide that information via API.

---

For a page you manage you could set up a [webhook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks) for the feed endpoint; that will get you updates for everything that happens on the feed - new posts, new comments, new reactions ... You’d have to filter out the reactions on your end, and then you could record them in your database with a timestamp that should be close enough. (That will only work for new reactions though, and not already existing ones.)

Comment: Can an app receive unlimited webhook events per hour, or is there a rate limit?

Comment: @Guus quote from docs, _"Frequency: Update notifications are aggregated and sent in a batch with a maximum of 1000 updates."_ - no further restrictions; the updates will be send no matter how heavy the activity on your page. But your server should be able to handle that, too, of course - you got only a few seconds to respond with 200 OK, before Facebook will consider the request a failure, and send the data again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can get details of comment by:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/{post-id}/reactions?access_token={page_token}
```

Comment: this doesnt give the time at which the reaction was added by the user.

Comment: As of now you cant get time of the reaction